# Pass parameter to controller, not method inside controller. MVC 5 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, ado.net

I'm looking to see if there is anyway to pass a parameter to the controller itself and not a method inside the controller.

I use named connection strings with parameters for my ADO.NET models. This means I must pass a parameter every time I call the model

```
MyEntities myentity = new MyEntities(Param);
```

We do this because each division in our company has it's own mirrored SQL server and when using data we want the local divisions data.

The problem I face is that I cannot put the connection to the Model outside of a Method because it requires a parameter.

What I currently have to do is this

```
namespace WebApps.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
            public ActionResult Index(string Param)
            {
                MyEntities myentity = new MyEntities(Param);
                var db = myentity.table;
                return View(db);
            }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is this...

```
namespace WebApps.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        MyEntities myentity = new MyEntities(Param);

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var db = myentity.table;
                return View(db);
            }
    }
}
```

This would also allow me to properly use a dispose method. I can't currently use it because I need to pass that parameter to close the db. (it doesn't exist outside the method)

This fails...

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Could anyone tell me if passing a parameter directly to the controller is possible?

Comment: From where would it get this Param?  I'm not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate because it's a bit older and things may have changed, but look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332159/constructor-with-parameter-in-controller-mvc

Comment: @stephen.vakil: My read is that he wants a constructor with a parameter that accepts `Param` (but my read may be wrong).

Comment: @EricJ. right, but where is `Param` instantiated? One alternative is a controller factory...

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm confusing you. If you look at a default scaffolded controller on an ADO.NET model it automatically puts the Entity connection outside of the ActionResult. So you're able to just call 'myentity' in any method in that controller. I instead have to call the entity inside every method, always passing a parameter from the View to the Method. I wanted to know if I can give the controller a parameter instead of always giving it to the methods... that does sound strange after I type it out...

Comment: @EricJ. That link is helpful. I'll see if it can get me what I need.

Comment: If the scenario is, on a page, you get some input from the user which determines which connection string to use, then having `MyEntities` instantiated in the action method makes sense, and you can use a `using` statement to ensure proper disposal.

Comment: @stephen.vakil You're correct. A connection string switcher is built into the View. I'll accept that as an aswer. Sounds easier than a controller factory (seems a little above my pay grade).